# Positionning element relatively in iOS (xcode layout)

Tags: ios, xcode, position

New in iOS, I would like to position element at the bottom of the screen.

Problem is elements at the bottom of 4" height screens are not displayed in 3,5" height screens.

I think it is a layout stuff.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the elements that are not being shown in 3.5 inch screen and set resizing as below.

Note: Solution will change if you are using auto-layout. To turn it off go to file inspector (Command + Option + 1) and uncheck the option.

[image]

Comment: I have to wait one minute

Answer (score 0):

You want to make the y offset relative to the screen size. Assuming a portrait mode, and that you created the element programatically, the calculation for y_offset would look something like:

```
([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)-(object_y_size + object_y_distance_from_screen_bottom)
```

Or, as a CGRect:

```
CGRectMake(your_x_offset, ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)-(object_y_size + object_y_distance_from_screen_bottom), object_x_size, object_y_size);
```